# Android JNI - thread synchronization

Tags: c++, multithreading, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a native C++ code, that I am calling from Android via JNI.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_myapp_CApi_setFoo(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring foo) {
    const char * fooStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(foo, 0);
    MyCApiSetFoo(fooStr);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(foo, fooStr);
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_myapp_CApi_getFoo(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    return env->NewStringUTF(MyCApiGetFoo());
}
```

All is working. However, `get` and `set` methods can be accessed from different threads and in that case, sometimes `get` is called before set. How can I solve thread synchronization? I am unable to edit underlying API.

I was thinking about use `std::unique_lock` inside each JNI method and create global `std::mutex` variable on which I will lock. Is this a good way, or is there some "standard" JNI way (I have found that there are monitors accesible from env).

I am also calling get very often (it is during OpenGL rendering loop), so performance is critical.

Comment: Declare them as`synchronized` at the Java level.

Comment: @ EJP For some methods it seems ok enough, but in some cases it is not neccessary to "lock" entire method, but only piece of it. Eg. in `setFoo`, I can lock only `MyCApiSetFoo`. In that case I should use what?

Comment: @MartynPerry None of that information appears in your question.

Comment: @EJP the logic is to lock the smallest part of the code possible, not entire method. Why to lock entire `setFoo`, if only part of it is sufficient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JNI way of locking a mutex is [`MonitorEnter`/`MonitorExit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5256).

That is, you can enter the same monitor that a java `synchronized` block would from java code.

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_myapp_CApi_setFoo(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jstring foo) {
    const char * fooStr = env->GetStringUTFChars(foo, 0);
    env->MonitorEnter(thiz); // same effect as synchronized(thiz) { ...
    MyCApiSetFoo(fooStr);
    env->MonitorExit(thiz);
    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(foo, fooStr);
}

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_myapp_CApi_getFoo(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    env->MonitorEnter(thiz);
    auto res = MyCApiGetFoo();
    env->MonitorExit(thiz);
    return env->NewStringUTF(res);
}
```

You can use any object to lock on, it doesn't have to be `thiz` if that isn't providing a sufficient level of locking granularity.

Alternatively, if you just need to lock a structure *internal* to the C++ code, use a static `std::mutex` with a `lock_guard`.